# Which Chasidic group departed the least from Ashkenazi minhag and nusach?

Tags: minhag, prayer-book, chasidut-hasidism, ashkenazi, nusach-ashkenaz

Chasidic groups vary in terms of their siddur's differences from nusach Ashkenaz, as well as their general minhagim and hashkafic approaches.

Is there a Chasidic group which most closely matches the regional customs prior to the advent of Chasidus?

Edit: I confess I have no idea how there could be one selectable correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 15):

Erlau.  They dress like Hassidim and they have a rebbe, who holds a tisch, but their traditions and minhagim are Chassam Sofer strictly (In fact, the Erlauer ravs are from the direct line of the Chassam Sofer, and their surname is in fact, Sofer.).  They use Ashkenaz siddur, and their culture is an Oberlander culture.

You'll also find, if you hang out with the Erlau community, that they tend to be much more sophisticated and worldly than regular Hassidim are.  Regular Hassidim are nice, sweet folks, but very simple and naive, whilst Erlau people, while also sweet and kind, seem quite educated.  Erlau has selectively adopted a few Hassidishims, but haven't betrayed their authentic traditions the way other Oberlander groups have.

Comment: Who are the "regular Hassidim"? I seem to have met simple and sophsticated people in every social group.

Comment: Although Erlau is often called Hasidic, I'm not sure if they are actually Hasidim or if they are just very old-fashioned Haredim. Do they have a Hasiduth?

Answer (score 5):

I've heard that Belz Chassidus uses Nusach Ashkenaz (or something close to it) for Shemoneh Esrei.

Answer (score 5):

Vien chassidim(oberlander Jews) Daven Ahskanaz even though some switched to sefard . They also initially wore homburg hats not shtreimals which chassidim traditionally wear.

Comment: To improve this answer, perhaps you should elaborate on what makes them more similar to Ashkenazi Jews than other Chassidim are.

Comment: The member of the Vien kehilla that daven Ashkenaz and wear Hamburgs would be livid if they see you calling them Chasiddim. I'm not saying that have anything against Chasidim (other than the fact that their keilla turned chasidish). They just would never consider themselves chasidim. PS, I'm from this kehilla.

Comment: @shmuly I dont disagree but thats what happened.

Comment: @Shmuly, that's interesting. What would they consider themselves? Do they have a Rebbe?

Comment: One more similarity between the Vien Chasidim and Ashkenaz - wrapping the Tefilin shel Yad towards the wearer.

Comment: Did they switch to Sefard or to HaAri?

Answer (score 3):

The Gerer shtible near me davens mincha **before** shki'a, but without tachanun. Also, they say "Boruch HaShem omain vomain" in Maariv.

Comment: They just never say tachanun? Ever?

Comment: Not to mincha as far as I have seen.

Comment: Outside of Breslov and Chabad, the majority of Chassidim do not say Tachnun because they hold of the opinion that you do not say tachnun on the yaharzeit of a tzaddik and there is a yaharzeit everyday.

Comment: It is true. The source is just about any Chassidic shuls. Even wikipedia holds of this but does not have a source.

Comment: And among those who do say _tachanun_, most skip it at _mincha_. I've long understood this to be because they typically say _mincha_ after _sh'kia_, when they'd skip _tachanun_; even if they say it early, then, they do so. @mochinrechavim

Comment: @msh210 This doesnt account for tachnun during Shachris which is also ommited. I have obviously not davening in every chassidic groups shul but Hungarish and Polish seem to not say tachnun stam.

Comment: @mochinrechavim, I said "mong those who do say _tachanun_". However, I understand some synagogues use a list of yahrzeits and do say _tachanun_ on any date not on that list (which is a minority).

Comment: Minhag HaGra - which is Ashkenaz - is not to say "Boruch HaShem omain vomain" in Maariv.

Comment: Hasn't there been a yahrtzeit of a tzaddik every day since, let's estimate, at least Churban Bayit Rishon? We know there were over 1200000 prophets who existed (even if we don't have most of their writings). If so, why has anyone said tachanun since then?

Comment: @GershonGold  How common is it for Ashkenazim to follow the Minhag HaGra on this?  I have always seen Ashkenazim include that berakah.  Which groups tend to follow this, Litvish?

Comment: @Mike: Yeshiva Rabeinu Chaim Berlin Daven's Ashkenaz and follows Minhag HaGra. They do not say Boruch Hashem L'Olam. I was at a Ashkenaz Minyan in Memphis which follows Minhag HaGra. They also did not say Boruch Hashem L'Olam.

Comment: @Mike In Israel it's very common. In Chutz La'aretz, less so.

Answer (score 3):

Erlau daven Nusach Ashkenaz in their main shul in Katamon, (and they are "culturally" hasidic in many ways). In fact, Erlau are more loyal to Minhag Ashkenaz that the vast majority of Nusach Ashkenaz shuls (except for the Yekkis of course). For example, from what I have heard, they say the traditional piyutim throughout the year, including the Marovis on Yom Tov night. So a visit to Erlau in Katamon is probably the closest we can get to a "traditional" Eastern European Nusach Ashkenaz davening, (even though many consider them Chasidim and they dress with streimels, have a rebbe, tish etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Belz davens Nusach Ashkenaz Shemona Esrei and they also say Baruch Hashem Le'Olam on Motzai Shabbos before Shemona Esrei.

The reason behind it is mentioned [here](https://www.worldofbelz.org/2019/02/08/sar-shalom-rav-rebbe-belz/).

Belz, as opposed to Viznitz, Gur and probably others as well, does daven Mincha after sh'kia but they do say tachanun during Mincha.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of [Carlebach-style minyanim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlebach_minyan) both in the U.S. and in the Holy Land of Israel that pray in Nusach Ashkenaz, and I do believe that [Reb Shlomo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Carlebach) was Chassidic.  However, there have in the past existed within other Chassidic groups multiple sets of minhagim.  One example is that there was a Chabad before Lubavitch.  I know this because the Baal HaTanya himself was from a place called Liadi, not Lubavitch.  He probably had Liadian (sp?) minhagim, not Lubavitcher ones.

Comment: Can any Chabad and/or Lubavitch readers confirm the latter bit?

Comment: In terms of halacha, Lubavitchers adhere to the Shulchan Aruch HaRav, written by the Baal HaTanya.  In terms of minhag, however, Chabad minhagim are codified in [Sefer HaMinhagim](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/), compiled about fifty years ago.  The last Lubavitcher Rebbe z'l described it as clarifying which particular minhag was the practice of the Chabad community where the S"A gave multiple opinions.

Comment: @yoel, Lubavitchers follow Sh"A HaRav, except where it is contradicted by his Siddur (which he wrote later). Double AA, Adam; Chabad had ties to the city of Lubavitch even prior to the Alter Rebbe; also, he actually studied there for several years as a child. Additionally, his family were chassidim of the BeSH"T, so it's likely that they followed his minhagim. Adam, while it's true that Chabad split into different groups (Lubavitch, Kopust etc.,) after the Tzemach Tzedek's passing, as far as I know, they all shared the minhagim of the Tz"Tz (i.e. Chabad). <-Someone may correct me on that point

Comment: Minhagim in europe were mostly family based, so there is no chiddush that it was any more in Chabad than any other group. Minhagim in Lubavitch have evolved and certain things that were done then aren't done now and other things were added by different Rebbeim. Even how Chassidus is explains differs from the Mitteler Rebbe to the Rebbe Rashab. The statement that "multiple minhagim" were kept needs explaination. Two minhagim for the same issue? Keeping a satmar minhag as well? Family minhag? Bottom line is you can replace Chabad with just about any group and make the statement work.

Comment: @HodofHod Yoel is simply saying the Alter Rebbe brings many opinions in his S.A. and explains why one opinion is chosen. Sefer HaMinhagim obviously doesnt work like that. One is halacha and the other is minhag. The siddur is meant for the Chassidim and the Shulchan Aruch is meant for Klal Yisroel. The siddur is a response to a statement made in the Alter Rebbe's shuchan aruch that when Kabbalah and Halacha disagree and Kabbalah is more machmir, we go with Kabbalah.

Comment: @mochinrechavim What's your source that the siddur is only for chassidim? I was under the impression that it was the Shaar HaKollel?

Comment: @HodofHod I was told by the publisher of a Chassidic Group who publishes their main siddur that all groups will claim that their siddur is the version of Nusach Arizal that is Shaar HaKollel :-D

Comment: @mochin ken zein, but you said that some hold it's only for chassidim.

Comment: @HodofHod I will try to find a source. I thought this was something well known.